# Issue in fetching metafiles within 'dep11' and 'i18n' directories for xenial under the section 'multiverse'

Tags: 16.04, deb, multiverse

Using debmirror, unable to download the metafiles within 'dep11' and 'i18n' directories for xenial under the section 'multiverse'.

```
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/multiverse/
```

**debmirror version: 1:2.25ubuntu2**

A similar issue has been reported in the the following bug, however it seems like a different issue (In the bug it's mentioned about 'main' section, however here the
issue is with 'multiverse' section)

```
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debmirror/+bug/1565585
```

Did anyone else experience this?